# Header JTable i18n in Netbeans

Tags: swing, internationalization, jtable

I applied to all components i18n of my forms, but I couldn`t internationalize JTable headers.
And I can not edit it because it's code generated by netbeans.
Any help?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit code generated by Netbeans with any editor you like. That is if you do not plan to use the Netbeans GUI designer anymore.

Probably the JTable headers of your application are hardwired in one language. You should change that and add them to your locale property files.

You can do it like this:

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private String[] headers;
    public TableModel() {
        java.util.ResourceBundle bundle = java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("internationals/Bundle"); // NOI18N
        headers = new String[3];
        headers[0] = bundle.getString("TableModel.header1.text");
        headers[1] = bundle.getString("TableModel.header2.text");
        headers[2] = bundle.getString("TableModel.header3.text");
    }
    ....
    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int i) {
        return headers[i];
    }
```

and prepare your locale property file like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi!Thanks! But how can I change that?? The Headers names are in Table Model and I don`t know how to change language there... I only change the language in the "properties" from the form

Comment: It is very straight forward. Here is an excellent Netbeans i18n tutorial you should read: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-automatic-i18n.html

Comment: Thanks!Yes finally I use the "User Code" option in Model Properties and put the code to call de key in the properties file...